# How many two digit numbers are not a multiple of 10

Tags: combinatorics

How many two digit numbers are not a multiple of 10.

9 *  9 = 81 correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. More importantly, your apparent computation strategy
$$\left(\;\text{# of choices for 1st digit}\;\right)\cdot \left(\;\text{# of choices for 2nd digit}\;\right)$$
is correct.

A less-sophisticated check: There are $99$ integers from $1$ to $99$. (They count themselves!) Of these, nine are single-digits numbers, and nine are multiples of $10$. So $99-9-9 = 81$ numbers remain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. The two digit numbers that are not a multiple of $10$ are the two digit numbers that do not contain a zero. Thus, there are $9\times9=81$ such numbers